# aws のスポットインスタンスは継続時間後必ず削除されるのか？

Tags: aws

aws のスポットインスタンスは、あらかじめ継続利用時間を指定できるようですが、この時間を指定した場合、その時間が過ぎれば必ずインスタンスは削除されるのでしょうか。(意図した以上に起動してしまって、その分課金されてしまうことはありませんか？)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

継続期間の指定をしたスポットインスタンスの料金は、指定した継続期間によって決まります。
時間経過後にインスタンスが残ったとしても、料金に加算されることはありません。

出典：　[スポットインスタンスリクエスト](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#fixed-duration-spot-instances)

Answer (score 0):

@Fumu7 さんに共有されたリンクを見ていました。マニュアルを見る限り、以下が条件のように読めました。本当にこれで正しいかどうかはちょっとわかっていませんが。。

- スポットインスタンスはあらかじめ継続時間を指定して起動することができる。この継続時間を指定すると、最大でもその時間だけインスタンスは実行されることになり、それ以上実行されることはない。なので、予定金額以上請求されることはない。
- 継続時間指定とは、一定時間のインスタンスの確保を求めるものであり、その分単位時間あたりの値段は、継続時間が長ければ長いほど釣り上がる。
- そもそも AWS の値段は１時間単位(切り上げ)で課金される
- インスタンスは継続時間が経過するか、ユーザーが自分で Terminate するかどちらか早い方のタイミングで破棄される。